# What is happening when R combines two vectors using c()?

Tags: r

When you concatenate two vectors in R using `c()`, it "combines the arguments and results in a vector". Does it combine them by creating a new vector to take on the elements of the two vectors or is there a way to literally combine the data spaces allocated for both vectors?

When I searched I couldn't find an explanation. The visual representations of `c()` all literally just attach the second vector to the end of the first vector, but I think that's just so we can easily understand what this function does and not what actually happens.

Comment: Here is the source code for `c()`: https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/ae690d891c16c2b0a12f90d7aa673b139444a878/src/main/bind.c#L778

Comment: A new vector is created when you use `c()`. It gets its own memory allocated.

Comment: @JonSpring I don't think that package allows symbols to be mapped to the memory of multiple existing vectors to simulate concatenation. Having pieces of vectors fragmented within the heap seems like a pretty bad idea for lots of reasons.

Comment: @AllanCameron, post these two comments (concatenated of course :-)) as an answer?

Comment: @BenBolker I find it quite involved to explain it  in any detail, but I have tried.

Comment: @AllanCameron more thorough than I would have expected! Thanks.

Comment: if you really need to concatenate huge vectors in a memory-efficient way, you *could* define a data structure which consists of an **environment** containing a set of vectors along with a table of lengths that allows for an indexing method that would automatically locate the correct sub-vector and element within that sub-vector ... however, this would still be tricky if you want to completely avoid copying. (A use case/reason for your question would be helpful, although pure curiosity is an acceptable reason to ask ...)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

When you call `c()`, a *new* vector is allocated, into which the existing vectors are combined. It happens [here](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/ae690d891c16c2b0a12f90d7aa673b139444a878/src/main/bind.c#L849C3-L849C55) in the underlying C code.

```cpp
PROTECT(ans = allocVector(mode, data.ans_length));
```

This might seem wasteful, since we already have the values written to memory, so why not just wrap up a couple of pointers to this memory and call *that* a vector?

There are several reasons for this.

Firstly, many of the arithmetic and statistical operations that R carries out on vectors are done by iterating through elements in contiguous memory. This would not be possible if the elements were not *in* contiguous memory. There would be a lot of address-checking steps and jumping between memory addresses, which would make things a lot slower. Outside of R, concatenating vectors in C or in C++ is also done by allocating a new vector, for much the same reason.

A second reason is to avoid fragmentation and memory leaks. If we created a vector from concatenating subsets of other vectors without allocating dedicated memory, we would end up with a bunch of pointers to different locations in the memory free store. If we then used subsets of *this* vector, we would have a nightmare of memory pointers to memory pointers to fragments of vectors, and chunks of unused fragments of vectors which could not be re-used or reclaimed by the garbage collector.

A third reason is that R users expect copy-on-modify behaviour. For example, if we have:

```r
a <- c(1, 2, 3)

b <- c(a, a)

b
#> [1] 1 2 3 1 2 3
```

Then we expect to be able to change a single element:

```r
b[6] <- 6

b
#> [1] 1 2 3 1 2 6
```

Whereas, if `b` did not have its own data allocated, this operation would change the third element of `b` as well as the sixth element.

As Nicola points out in the comments, another reason is that `c` will carry out type checking and implicit conversion between types to ensure that the underlying storage mode of the new vector is consistent. This allows some straightforward and well-defined flexibility between integers, doubles, logical vectors, factors and character strings which would be impossible if vectors created by `c` were composed of pieces of existing vectors.

---

Conceptually, the memory allocation in R works like this: each R object is stored in C as a `SEXP` object. This is a structure which is basically a pointer to the data itself, which is stored in memory as a structure called a `SEXPREC`.

Therefore, if we run the code:

```r
A <- 1:4
B <- 5:14
```

the vectors `A` and `B` might be stored in memory like this:

[image]

If we then do

```r
C <- c(A, B)
```

Then in memory we get:

[image]

With the data in the SEXPREC pointed to by `C` having been copied from the data in the two other SEXPREC objects pointed to by `A` and `B`

Comment: super comprehensive demonstration to show the memory allocation! +1!

Comment: Maybe it's worth to mention that `c` actually does much more than just combining vectors. It also *coerces* them to a common type. That's another reason why you don't just have references to the argument objects (or you couldn't combine vectors of different type together)

Comment: Good point @nicola. I've added a paragraph with attribution.

Comment: @AllanCameron While this discussion focuses more on the _contents_ of a vector than its attributes, I'd note that `c()` also **combines and propagates** the `names` of nested vectors. So `c(x = c(y = 1, z = 2))` yields `c(x.y = 1, x.z = 2)`, and `c(x = 1:2)` yields `c(x1 = 1, x2 = 2)`. It also **composes** these operations: `c(x = c(y = 1:2))` yields `c(x.y1 = 1, x.y2 = 2)`.  I mention it because I've spent a long week [modeling this behavior](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/289078) with M, toward a [**`tidyselect`** syntax in Power Query](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/288977).